# Windows 2016 Group Policy Administrative Templates

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016

In my 2016 Active Directory Server in the Group Policy under the Administrative Templates tab I am not getting anything.  On my old 2012 AD server there was a plethora of options to choose from.  I have downloaded some Secure Host Baseline templates (.admx) files that I would like to import.  However, when I try to add these templates it tells me that it only accepts .adm files.  The ADM files were used back in Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 5):

"Import" is accomplished by copying the admx/adml files to %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions folder (the default location) where you will run Group Policy Management Console. The .adml files are copied to %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\xx-xx, where xx-xx is the language code.

Or if you use a Group Policy Central Store, %systemroot%\SYSVOL\[domain]\Policies\PolicyDefinitions on one of your domain controllers, where it will be replicated to the other domain controllers in your domain. If you have a domain that was upgraded from 2003, the SYSVOL directory may be SYSVOL_DFSR.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2011/12/12/how-to-implement-the-central-store-for-group-policy-admin-templates-completely-hint-remove-those-adm-files/